# Can Windows Environment Variables Be Set to Integers/Numbers

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I am new to working with the Windows environment so I wanted to know if it was possible to set the value of an environment variable to a number (like an int) or something other than a string. I am trying to do this via a PowerShell script using the `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` method. For example, if I wanted to create an environment variable to track the number of entries in my PATH I would do something like this:

```
$count = 0
$pathEntries = @([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "User") -split ";")
foreach ($entry in $pathEntries){
$count += 1
}
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH_COUNT", $count, "User")
```

I am using PATH as an example and I know this is probably not the best way to do this but I just wanted to know if Windows environment variables could hold integer or other numeric data types.

Comment: Been a long time since I've worked with them, but as I recall back when environment variables were not strongly typed. You'd just dump whatever characters you wanted in them, digits or otherwise. If you subsequently used such a varable, I think there were ways to first check if it could be treated as a numeric or not.

Comment: Your code works but the call to `SetEnvironmentVariable` implicitly converts the number `$count` to a `string`, [as the 2nd parameter is typed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0#system-environment-setenvironmentvariable(system-string-system-string-system-environmentvariabletarget)).

Comment: environment variables are always strings

Comment: As Philip says, `You'd just dump whatever characters you wanted in them`. Thing is, is that environment variables are available across the whole environment, even to systems that are not strongly typed! so it cannot be strongly typed. Here is an answer to the exact same question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162288/16106482

Comment: In short: Environment variables are _invariably_ strings, but you're free to parse them as / cast them to a different data type; e.g. `[int] $env:PATH_COUNT`

Comment: Been a while since I asked this, but yeah, the consensus answer is that these variables are not like data types in a .NET application. They're basically strings. I figured out how to cast them to numeric types in my PowerShell scripts. I actually created several scripts since I asked this question that made use of environment variables, pretty simple actually. Thank you to everyone for your answers; they were really helpful.